# Nesting async/await calls in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I am pretty new to async/await for ASP.NET MVC and have a quick question about it. My question is it necessary to use async/await on nested calls to a database? For instance:

UnitOfWork.cs

```
public async Task CommitAsync()
{
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

AccountService.cs

```
public async Task SaveLoginAttemptAsync(LoginAttempt loginAttempt)
{
     _appContext.Repository<LoginAttempt>().Add(loginAttempt);
     await _appContext.UnitOfWork.CommitAsync();
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
//..
var attempt = new LoginAttempt()
{
    Email = User.Identity.GetEmail(),
    Logintime = DateTime.Now,
    Successful = successful ? "Y" : "N",
    IpAddress = Request.UserHostAddress,
    UserId = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId())
 };
 await _accountService.SaveLoginAttemptAsync(attempt);
//..
```

Are the async/await methods on SaveLoginAttemptAsync in the AccountService.cs and the code block in AccountController.cs necessary since the end point uses async/await?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with async/await it's turtles all the way down. Doing otherwise will mess with your debugging experience.

Technically you can skip the `await` on all the "deeper" returns since you aren't relying on the return value in that context. However, you don't really want to.

If you skip the await and return a `Task`, then the method won't be in the callstack while you are debugging since it's actually `await`ing on the Task it returned, not the code in the method itself.

Comment: Also, on non UI code (code not in the controller) all awaited tasks should have a call to `ConfigureAwait(false)`.